# Just how small a point is required for the Pauli Exclusion Principle to apply when looking at LQG?

Tags: pauli-exclusion-principle, loop-quantum-gravity

In Loop Quantum Gravity, the thought is that the smallest possible point is 10^-35 meters.  But it is recognized that this is still not a singularity, which basically has no dimensions.  So when it comes to the Pauli Exclusion Principle, is a single LQG particle small enough for it to apply?  Or do we need to get down to a singularity?  Could you pack a lot of 1/2 spin particles into a single LQG point?

Comment: If the smallest length scale is 10^-35m then a particle cannot have length less than that.

Comment: What does the Pauli exclusion principle have to do with a singularity?

Comment: The PEP says that you can't have two 1/2 spin particles in the same quantum state, so that would be in the same singularity, correct?

Comment: PEP says that you cant have two half integer spin particles in the same quantum state.And if there isnt a length smaller than 10^-35 m singularities dont exist.

Comment: @MissMulan  what I'm trying to understand is if PEP is a factor in a LQG particle, or if it is not.

Comment: Read my comments and you will get your answer.

Comment: @MissMulan  I'm not asking if singularities exist. That's a different question. I'm asking if two half-spin particles can exist in a LQG particle?  Or more specifically, can 10^50 half spin particles exist in a LQG particle?   Does the PEP only apply in a singularity?  Or does it apply in some space larger than a singularity?