# Taking into account the Pauli Exclusion Principle, how many particles can you cram into a really small space?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, heisenberg-uncertainty-principle, estimation, pauli-exclusion-principle

I'm trying to understand the basic concept of the Pauli Exclusion Principle, but [my former question here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/704863/just-how-small-a-point-is-required-for-the-pauli-exclusion-principle-to-apply-wh?noredirect=1#comment1577175_704863) did not provide an answer.  So let me rephrase it.

One way of describing the PEP is that you can't have two particles in the same quantum state, in the same place at the same time.  So let's take a really small space, say 1 Planck length square (but if that is not suitable please choose another size).  How many spin-half or spin-one particles can we cram into that space?  At what size of space does the PEP apply?

Comment: *"One way of describing the PEP is that you can't have two particles in the same place at the same time."* No, that's misleading (at best). You can't have two fermions in the same *state*. There's more to quantum state than position.

Comment: @PM2Ring  ok, then if we have two fermions with the same spin, (and any other criteria of "state") then just how small is the space that precludes them from being together?  What I am trying to understand is the size of the space at which the PEP applies?

Answer (score 5):

In principle, any finite volume can contain an unlimited number of identical fermions. But the smaller the volume, the larger the spacing between nearby energy levels, and, due to PEP, the higher the smallest possible energy of this system.

Only in the limit of the volume approaching zero will it be impossible to have more than one fermion in this volume. This is because the second energy level (and thus all the higher ones) grows indefinitely as the volume approaches zero.

Now, real-world particles interact, and identical particles almost always interact repulsively. Also, the potential well that would contain them would definitely be finite. This means that, once you have large enough quantity of fermions in a small potential well, this system will leak: some the particles will leave this potential well until total energy of the remaining ones is small enough to be contained by the potential barrier surrounding the well.

Comment: Can you give me a real world (or perhaps black hole) example?   Would you be able to contain a planet's worth of fermions in a Planck length cube?  Or what larger space would be required?

Comment: @foolishmuse I don't know of a really large example, but einsteinium atom has 99 electrons in a rather small space of about 400 pm in diameter. (Also, I've edited my answer with some information on limitations of this application of PEP.)

Comment: So we are talking about a space on the order of 10^-10 metres, which is a lot larger than a Planck length.  Thanks. I understand the scale now.

Comment: @foolishmuse for a larger scale the potential well must be deeper. This is a consequence of the PEP.

Comment: At some point, wouldn't the energy density reach a point at which gravitational effects would no longer be negligible, meaning ordinary quantum mechanics could no longer be used?

Comment: @Sandejo indeed, it would. The above answer ignores gravity. Moreover, it also ignores some relativistic effects like [Klein paradox](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Klein_paradox), which makes infinite potential wells impossible and even non-approachable.

Comment: I've just been reading on Planck Stars.  According to what you've said, under the PEP there is no way that the fermions in a star could collapse to that size, but the bosons could.

Comment: "Only in the limit of the volume approaching zero will it be impossible to have more than one fermion in this volume." If something is >1 for all values greater than zero, then the limit approaching zero is >1.

Comment: @Acccumulation then $\lim\limits_{x\to1^+}x>1$

Answer (score 0):

This is a complicated business, but much work on it has been done in the context of predicting the structure of supermassive star cores, white dwarf structure, and neutron stars. An astrophysics text on these topics will probably tell you what you need.